# What is the difference between border-collapse: collapse; and border-spacing: 0;

Tags: html, css, border-spacing

Is

```css
border-collapse:collapse;
```

and

```css
border-spacing: 0px;   /* only active/useful with option "separate" */
border-collapse:separate;
```

the same?

Comment: not so simple for me. I see quite often {border-spacing: 0px; 
border-collapse:collapse;}, which for me seems redundant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**They are Different!** (See Snippet below to confirm).

---

According to MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

> The `border-collapse` CSS property determines whether a table's borders
>   are separated or collapsed. In the separated model, adjacent cells
>   each have their own distinct borders. In the collapsed model, adjacent
>   table cells share borders.

and

> The `border-spacing` CSS property specifies the distance between the
>   borders of adjacent table cells (only for the separated borders
>   model). This is equivalent to the `cellspacing` attribute in
>   presentational HTML, but an optional second value can be used to set
>   different horizontal and vertical spacing.
>
> The `border-spacing` value is also used along the outside edge of the
>   table, where the distance between the table's border and the cells in
>   the first/last column or row is the sum of the relevant (horizontal or
>   vertical) `border-spacing` and the relevant (top, right, bottom, or
>   left) padding on the table.
>
> This property applies **only** when `border-collapse` is `separate`.

---

So here is a **SNIPPET**  with a few examples

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  margin:30px 0
}
td {
  border: 1px solid red
}
.collapse {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.separate {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
.no-spacing {
  border-spacing: 0
}
.spacing {
  border-spacing: 10px
}
```

```html
<h4>Borders will collapse and therefore no space between them</h4>
<table class="collapse no-spacing">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>Borders will try to separate between them but then using border-spacing:0 will join the borders without collpasing (looking like has double borders)</h4>
<table class="separate no-spacing">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />

<h3> 2 more examples </h3>
<h4>Border-spacing won't work due to only applies when border-collapse isset to separate</h4>
<table class="collapse spacing">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<h4>Borders will separate between them due to having border-spacing:10px and because border-collapse has separate as initial value</h4>
<table class="spacing">
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The 'double-lines' inside the table (but not for the general table frame) with "border-spacing: 0px;"  is it. It is really not esthetic in my opinion. So I assume normally a simple "border-collapse:collapse;" is what is wanted for excel-like grids and tables. Thanks.